# Not able to set JAVA_HOME variable in ubuntu 14.04 on manual installation

Tags: java, ubuntu, jakarta-ee, java-home

I've downloaded java jdk1.8.0.7.tar.gz file from the official website and unzipped it into my home directory. Now to set the `$JAVA_HOME` variable I used the follwing commands command `nano .bashrc` and then appending `export $JAVA_HOME=/home/shivam/Java/jdk1.8.0.7` at the end of the file . 
 But whenever I run the command `sudo $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh` I get an error message saying

```
Neither the JAVA_HOME nor the JRE_HOME environment variable is defined
At least one of these environment variable is needed to run this program
```

I don't understand why it is unable to find the java path though I've installed tomcat and set its home variable the this way, which worked.
I wan't to install Java manually **without using** `apt-get`.
 Kindly guide .

Comment: Did you open a new shel or logout and re-login after changing your .bashrc?

Comment: @penguineer Yes I did opened a new shell but no help.

Comment: Why are you using `sudo`?

Comment: @SteveC thanks. Running the command without sudo worked for me. I had set the variable for normal user and not for su.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to append the following to .bashrc:

```
JAVA_HOME=/home/shivam/Java/jdk1.8.0.7
```

Note the missing `$` at the start.

Also remember that the file won't effect your current shell without `source`ing it first.

Also, when running a command with `sudo`, you are running it as the `root` user, not as yourself. So the environment variable needs to be set for the root user, not yourself.

You can run `sudo env | grep JAVA_HOME` to see whether it is set for root.

Comment: My .bashrc file looks like this   export CATALINA_HOME=/home/shivam/Java/apache-tomcat-8.0.30

 export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/Java8/jdk1.8.0_71/

Comment: Thanks alot. It worked. I needed to run the command as a normal user and not as su. But now while using eclipse whenever I try to start the server it says the "Tomcat failed to start" without giving me any specific error.

Answer (score 1):

Have you run `.bashrc` ?

```
source .bashrc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add the following `2` lines in your `.bashrc` file:

```
JAVA_HOME=/home/shivam/Java/jdk1.8.0.7/
export JAVA_HOME
```

Comment: Sorry but I want to install it manually without using apt-get.